# How to show the vertical line between two columns?

Tags: two-column, rules

Simply using `\twocolumn` changes my document to look like this:

```
-----HEADER----
######   ######
######   ######
######   ######
######   ######
######   ######
######   ######
-----FOOTER----
```

But I'd like to make the line between two columns visible like this:

```
-----HEADER----
###### | ######
###### | ######
###### | ######
###### | ######
###### | ######
###### | ######
-----FOOTER----
```

What command will make the line visible?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use `\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}`.

EDIT: Obviously, you may freely choose the thickness of the column-separating line. I suggested `0.4pt` because standard LaTeX uses this value for rules above footnotes and around `fbox`es.

Comment: Thanks, and if I want to make it invisible again do I just modify {0.4pt} -> {0pt} ?

Comment: Yes. Should you want to change settings mid-document, `\setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}` will take effect starting with the page where the command was placed.

Answer (score 24):

You can use the `multicol` package (*edit:* not required in fact) and adjust those settings:

```
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.2pt}
```

Comment: what if i'm not using multicol, but partition my page manually with `flowfram`?