# How to put align two things between a long vertical bar?

Tags: formatting, vertical-alignment

Basically what I want is something like this

```
###### | ######
###### | ######
###### | ######
###### | ######
###### | ######
###### | ######
```

where # represents a derivation for an equation or something. I also cannot figure out the vertical line option with just `\vline[30pt]`.

Comment: It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  As it is a simple `\begin{tabular}{l|l} <left content> & <right content> \end{tabular}` will produce output with a vertical bar.

Comment: Related: [How to show the vertical line between two columns?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23887/5764)

Comment: \begin{align} \end{align} doesn't work inside tab

Comment: And this takes us back to my first comment: a MWE would be helpful to really understand your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comments it appears that you want to be able to use an `align` environment inside a tabular.  If that is the case then you need to wrap the `align` within a `\parbox`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l|l} 
left content & right content\\ 
left content & right content\\ 
\parbox{0.3\linewidth}{%
    \begin{align*} 
        E &= mc^2 \\ 
        F &=ma
    \end{align*}} & right content\\ 
left content & right content\\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can indeed use `tabular` type of environments, alternatively, you can use the `minipage` environment which may give you more flexibility with what you want to achieve:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\linewidth}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\vline
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\linewidth}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{align*}
x^2 + y^2 &= 1\\ 
y &= \sqrt{1 - x^2}.
\end{align*}
\begin{align}
u &= \arctan x & dv &= 1 \, dx\\ 
du &= \frac{1}{1 + x^2} dx & v &= x.
\end{align}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

This will give:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the `multicol` package. You can make the line separating the columns visible by setting `\columnseprule` to something greater than `0pt`. The advantage of this technique is that content can flow from one column to the next.

## Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[]{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage[]{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm} % space between columns
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt} % vertical line thickness

\usepackage[]{microtype}

\usepackage[]{lipsum} %<---used only to generate dummy text

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\lipsum[1]
%
\begin{align}
a^2+b^2&=c^2\\
F&=ma\\
K&=\frac{1}{2}mv^2
\end{align}
%
\lipsum[2]

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

## Example Output:

[image: example output]