# How to produce a two column text with separation line with single-column title and end text

Tags: titles, two-column

[image]

How can I produce the file as a PDF in LaTeX. I have done the following

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
```

But I have the following problem. I want to put the Title inside a box which has thick lines. Also if I use the `\maketitle` command, date comes below the title, which I do not wish to have.

Also I want to separate the column by a line of specified thickness.

Command lines will be useful.

Comment: To avoid having the date printed, you can use `\date{}`.

Comment: @JohnWickerson: John, but it still leaves a gap for the date. After Title I don't want to have enough gap for the content to begin.

Comment: Separating the columns with a line of specified thickness is tackled in this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23888/25356

Comment: @JohnWickerson: I m quite satisfied with \date{}. It works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol} % Works a bit better than twocolumn

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt} % thickness of line between cols
\setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt} % thickness of lines drawn by \fbox

\newcommand*\boxedtext[1]{%
  \begin{center}
    \fbox{\Huge\textbf{#1}}
  \end{center}
}

\begin{document}
\boxedtext{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\medskip % A little vertical space after the title

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{multicols}

\vfill % Align the rest against the bottom of the current page
\boxedtext{END}

\end{document}
```

[image]